# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLenght()

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I add use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` and `schema :: defaultStringLenght (120);` in file `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and I run cmd `php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy`
 to install cms to travel but it me in error.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        schema::defaultStringLenght(120);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made spell mistake. It would be `defaultStringLength`

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(120);
```